# Contar alumnos con promedio alto

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentado sacar estudiantes con promedio total sean superior a 75, solo la cantidad por gestión, carrera y sede.

Tengo una tabla maestra donde se almacena toda esta información:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|alumno_id|nota_promedio|carrera|id_sede|id_gestion|id_semestre|
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1        | 85.53      | SIS   | 1     | 20       | 1         |
| 2        | 50.35      | SIS   | 1     | 20       | 1         |
| 1        | 83.00      | SIS   | 1     | 21       | 2         |
| 2        | 50.20      | SIS   | 1     | 21       | 2         |
| 3        | 55.00      | ADM   | 2     | 21       | 1         |
| 4        | 15.50      | ADM   | 2     | 21       | 1         |
| 1        | 20.50      | SIS   | 1     | 22       | 3         |
| 2        | 85.50      | SIS   | 1     | 22       | 3         |
```

Lo que intento sacar es lo siguiente:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
|id_gestion|id_sede|carrera|id_semestre|cantidad_75|total_alumnos|
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 20       | 1     |SIS    | 1         | 1         | 2           |
| 21       | 1     |SIS    | 2         | 1         | 2           |
| 21       | 1     |AMD    | 1         | 0         | 2           |
| 22       | 1     |SIS    | 3         | 0         | 2           |
```

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select id_gestion, 
       id_sede, 
       carrera, 
       max(id_semestre) id_semestre, 
       count(DISTINCT alumno_id) alumnos_total
from tabla_maestra
group by id_sede, 
         id_gestion, 
         carrera, 
         id_semestre
```

Con eso agrupo gestiones, sedes, carreras y semestres y realizo el conteo total de estudiantes por cada agrupación, funciona todo bien.

Pero ahora como logro obtener la cantidad de estudiantes con promedio sumado hasta el momento, me explico:

Quiero sumar y sacar su promedio del estudiante hasta la gestión x, es decir para el `id_gestion` 21 el `id_alumno` 1 se suma `85.53+83.00` y promediarlo y si llega a 75 realizar el conteo para tal gestión, como se muestra en la segunda tabla.

Comment: Que gestor de bases de datos usas?

Comment: Sql Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

la query que deberias usar es la siguiente:

```
    SELECT id_gestion
    ,id_sede
    ,carrera
    ,id_semestre
    ,sum(iif(nota_promedio >= 75, 1, 0)) AS cantidad_75
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT alumno_id) AS total_alumnos
FROM tabla_maestra
GROUP BY id_gestion
    ,id_sede
    ,carrera
    ,id_semestre
```

En el caso de que el alumno para esa carrera, gestion y sede sea superior a 75, se contaría, en caso contrario, no se tiene en cuenta para la suma.

Para el caso de id_semetre, no seria necesario hacer el max.

Si tienes alguna duda, no dudes en comentarlo.